# How would I combine multiple columns into one new column in r based on condition/value

Tags: r, tidyverse, multiple-columns

| City | Age | Name | Q11_1 | Q11_4 | Q11_5 | Q11_6 | Q11_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .... | .... | ... | **yes** | no | no | no | no |
| ... | ... | ... | no | **yes** | no | no | no |
| ... | ... | ... | no | no | **yes** | no | no |
| ... | ... | ... | no | no | no | **yes** | no |
| ... | .. | ... | no | no | no | no | **yes** |
| ... | ... | ... | no | no | no | no | no |
| .. | ... | ... | no | no | no | no | no |

I have a dataset that looks like this table where people were asked if they have any specific diseases (Q11 columns), and they can only select yes to one column. But each disease is separated into multiple columns, and I want to create a new column named Diagnosis, that lists the disease they have instead of the yes or no values. I would like this new column to have four values: where if Q11_1== yes, then the value would be "Alzheimer". If Q11_4== yes, then the value is "Dementia". Q11_5== yes, then value is "Parkinson", and if Q11_6 or Q11_7== yes, then value is "other"

I tried using the ifelse statement using this code with the tidyverse library:

df %>% mutate(diagnosis= ifelse(Q11_1== "Yes", "Alzheimer", NA), ifelse(Q11_4 == "Yes", "Dementia", NA), ifelse(Q11_5 == "Yes", "Parkinson", NA))

But realized I am just adding multiple columns. Im trying to just add an extra column to the existing dataset that looks like this table below where it has the value of either "Alzheimer", "dementia","parkinson",or "other".

| Diagnosis |
| --- |
| Alzheimer |
| Dementia |
| Parkinson |
| other |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9q3u.png)

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical case of pivot_longer:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read.table(text="City   Age Name    QAlzheimer  QDementia   QParkinson  QFTD    QLewy
....    ....    ... yes no  no  no  no
... ... ... no  yes no  no  no
... ... ... no  no  yes no  no
... ... ... no  no  no  yes no
... ..  ... no  no  no  no  yes
... ... ... no  no  no  no  no
..  ... ... no  no  no  no  no
", header=TRUE)

data %>%
    pivot_longer(matches("^Q"),names_to="Diagnosis",names_prefix="Q") %>%
    filter(value == "yes") %>%
    select(-value)
```

Data then becomes:

```
  City  Age   Name  Diagnosis
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    
1 ....  ....  ...   Alzheimer
2 ...   ...   ...   Dementia 
3 ...   ...   ...   Parkinson
4 ...   ...   ...   FTD      
5 ...   ..    ...   Lewy
```

Comment: No need of `mutate`. just `data %>% pivot_longer(matches("^Q"),names_to="Diagnosis", names_prefix = "Q")` should remove the `Q`. Good answer

Comment: `df %>% pivot_longer(starts_with("Q"), names_prefix = "Q", values_transform = ~na_if(.x,"no"), values_drop_na = TRUE)`

Comment: Think I'll leave it with the filter and select for now, not to make it too condenced

Comment: Sure. I already upvoted. Its a good solution

Comment: OP's data has column names like "Q11_1", rather than having the disease names encoded directly. A `pivot_longer` solution, while elegant, would not produce the desired result based on what we know about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If there is ATMOST one `yes` per row, In base R you could do:

```
df$diagnosis <- "other"
idx <- which(df=='yes', TRUE)
df$diagnosis[idx[,1]] <- names(df)[idx[,2]]

  City  Age Name QAlzheimer QDementia PQarkinson QFTD QLewy  diagnosis
1 .... ....  ...        yes        no         no   no    no QAlzheimer
2  ...  ...  ...         no       yes         no   no    no  QDementia
3  ...  ...  ...         no        no        yes   no    no PQarkinson
4  ...  ...  ...         no        no         no  yes    no       QFTD
5  ...   ..  ...         no        no         no   no   yes      QLewy
6  ...  ...  ...         no        no         no   no    no      other
7   ..  ...  ...         no        no         no   no    no      other
```

If there are more than one `yes` per row, you will have to aggregate them eg, paste,tostring, list, etc before you assign to the row.